# what is for ServiceUrl("/api/reports/") in Telerik Reports

Tags: telerik, report, reporting, telerik-mvc, telerik-reporting

```
$reportViewer = $("#reportViewer1")
    .telerik_ReportViewer({
        serviceUrl: "/api/reports/",
        templateUrl: '/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate.html',
        reportSource: { report: "MyClassLib.Group, MyClassLib" },
        viewMode: telerikReportViewer.ViewMode.Interactive,
        scaleMode: telerikReportViewer.ScaleModes.SPECIFIC,
        scale: 1.0,
        PersistSession: false
    });
```

I wonder especially how serviceUrl works or where is /api/reports/
if you please tell other parameters i would be happy.

Thanks

Comment: You're better looking at Telerik's API documentation or asking them directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Here is the link](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/html5-report-viewer-jquery-fn-telerik-reportviewer.html)**   what all client-side properties explained